# Yii2: Class 'Yii' not found

Tags: php, yii2

I was learning Yii framework a few days ago. I facing with the error below:

> Fatal error: Class 'Yii' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginForm\views\user\views\default\register.php on line 17

[image]

Comment: can you confirm what version of yii2 are you using by typing in `./yii` at the document root of your project using terminal and hit enter. it should print the ver first line with the yii version

Answer (score 2):

Try this first row:

```
use Yii;
//other use statements
```

and then:

```
Yii::$app->...
```

OR you can make it work this way to:

```
  \Yii:$app->...
```

Comment: I try the first row, and got the error 'The use statement with non-compound name 'Yii' has no effect'

Comment: Are you trying this in `view` file? after `<?php` and also try to do in statement, both ways should work.

Comment: @TommyChong you might be using an older version of Yii2 and need update the framework

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I use composer to update the Yii framwork, after that if still not working, I have use Yii; but it unused

Comment: This is pointless in this case - `use Yii;` or leading backslash are relevant only in namespaced context, views uses global namespace so `Yii::` works always the same.

Comment: @rob006 see the question: `Fatal error: Class 'Yii' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginForm\views\user\views\default\register.php on line 17`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Believe me, I've seen it. It does not change anything - your advice is pointless on OP's case (using `Yii` in global context).

Comment: @rob006 It does work on my end too (Without any backslash), but this error does says that Yii not found. It may be an php misconfiguration, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Yii is present in the root folder of the project. So you need to tell the program where to locate it. Either write:

use Yii

at the top along with the other use statements, or put a backslash before Yii like:
\Yii